# Calling member function that uses class attributes in another member function

Tags: c++

I have a member function that calls another member function, in which I use class' private attributes, and it takes another pointer to the class as a parameter.

Now, I want to reach my class' attributes and after calculations, copy them to the other object pointer that I took as a parameter. It's a bit confusing when explaining, but I believe it's a simple code. Yet I get "segmentation fault" when i try to reach my class' attributes. Code is below:

inside my Image class:

```
Image *Image::new_gray(int width, int height)
{
        return new Image(width, height, 1);
}

void Image::box_filter_x(Image *buffer, int n)
{
        printf("in box x func.\n");

        printf("%d\n", m_width);  
//m_width is class attribute. here i get segmentation fault and
//rest of the code doesn't run, obviously.

        printf("m_width read, calculating further.\n");
        ....
        buffer->m_width = m_width;
        ....
}


void Image::box_filter(Image *dst, int n)
{

        printf("%d\n", m_width);
//this works as expected.

        box_filter_x(dst, n);
//this is where i call my function.

}
```

Inside main function in another file where i do tests:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        Image* gray = Image::new_gray(128, 128);
        ...
        Image* gray1 = Image::new_gray(128, 128);
        ...
        gray->box_filter(gray1, 3);
}
```

I tried `this->box_filter_x(dst,n);` but that didn't work either.
Help please.

Comment: `Segmentation fault` means you are attempting access memory outside your control. The example given looks ok. So there must be something else where memory is being manipulated.  Can you port where exacly the error is happening?

Comment: Sounds like an allocation issue. What does `Image::new_gray()` do?

Comment: @AbbysSoul I get it at the line where i call m_width in box_function_x. The line above it works, but anything below doesn't. so it must be about m_width, i think?

Comment: @Chipster returns a new Image class with width, height and channel=1 as parameter.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58757412/edit) and add it?

Comment: @Chipster I added it, please have a look

Comment: Well, `new_gray()` looks okay. To be clear, the line `printf("%d\n", m_width);` executes and gives a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Chipster Yes, that's the exact line I'm getting the error.

Comment: Hmm. Well, the code you posted isn't problematic that I can tell. Perhaps you should reduce it to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add that here.

Comment: What is the type of m_width? There is nothing obvious with the code you provided. I can only assume the error is in the parts we have not seen yet.

Comment: @Chipster Okay, I will try to do so and let you know again if I can't solve it until tomorrow.

Comment: @AbbysSoul It's `int`. The code is part of a private project so I can't show much of it unfortunately... I can't think of any other problematic part though. I will try to find the source of it to the best I can and let you know if I can't solve it.

Comment: Could you please provide the image constructors

Comment: If you're getting mystery segfaults it might be time to step into a debugger.  Set a breakpoint on that last known non-erroring, and step until you hit the segfault. That will hopefully tell you what pointer is bad, and the state of your variables right before it blew up.